# Reverse Engineering Visio Pro Office 365

Tags: sql-server, office365, reverse-engineering, visio, erd

I am attempting to create an ERD of my SQL Server database and wanted to use the Reverse Engineering Wizards in my 2016 Visio Pro Office 365.  I am following this article:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Reverse-engineer-an-existing-database-into-a-database-model-fb034862-acfc-45bc-88b2-f33d1e1f8614

I have installed the add-in and been able to select the Database Model Diagram but I am unable to find the 'Database tab, in the Manage group'.   I have looked through all the tabs in visio options but there is no database tab listed.

Any Suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing ... You installed the addin, but did not start from the proper template. That's step 1 in the link you mentioned (Click the File tab, click New, click Templates, click Software and Database, and then double-click Database Model Diagram.).
Tabs for special solutions are often controlled by templates.

Answer (score 0):

Another guess: your organization is on "default" (standard) release channel. You can check that in your organization's profile on the Office 365 admin app. AFAIK, you need the latest Visio version ("First Release" version) to make the extension work. Or you could try that at least :)

Learn more about those options and how to switch them [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-up-the-Standard-or-First-Release-options-in-Office-365-3b3adfa4-1777-4ff0-b606-fb8732101f47)

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with Visio with my first download and had to re-download to get it working from there i had an easier time creating a Database Source from searching for "ODBC Data Sources" in windows explorer. When trying to create a new DB source in Visio it wouldnt make it to the list...